# the font size on the receipt is different when printing using different types of smartphones

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, printing, font-size

I'm having problems where every time I print receipts on various devices the font size will be different and sometimes the receipt can't load all the content according to what has been set.  here I use the Printooth library and use Layout which is then converted to a bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I think you used dp. please used sdp and try.

Comment: I set the font size programmatically and tried to convert the font size with this code

val pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                4f,
                context.resources.displayMetrics
            )

, is the code correct?

Comment: Why you set the size programmatically. If you have a big project or more than 50 screen so it's not good for the set all size programmatically. sdp is best.

Comment: Since my client requires everything to be dynamic including the font size, it will be setup via the web client, so why am I setting it programmatically, and this project is a big project